# How to Check Installed Packages in MSYS2

Tags: package, command, msys2

This is a very simple question, but I'm not sure how to query the installed packages and their versions in MSYS2. I have read the MSYS2 wiki [here](https://www.msys2.org/docs/package-management/) and the Arch Linux wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman), but they do not seem to mention it or I missed it. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: It appears the wikis do cover this as mentioned by the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since msys2 is based on `pacman`, you can use typical `pacman` commands.
For example, in this case use `pacman -Q` to list installed packages (many additional flags to customize the search are available).

Further reading:

[msys2 package management](https://www.msys2.org/docs/package-management/)

[Pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman)